# Regular Expression for exact match of either 4 integers or 2 doubles in a line

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to identify lines in a file that have either 4 integer or 2 double values. My regular expression is as below:

```
 var match = new Regex(@"^(?<Values>(((\d+\s*){4})|(\d+\.\d+\s*){2}))$");
```

Sample of lines in the file getting parsed:

```
element 1 2
8 24 2 1 1
0 1 129
2 2 0 0 
30.200001 1000.0000
208 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
.....
.....
```

Here, my regular expression matches correctly for above lines no 4 & 5. That's ok. But, it's also matching line no 3 (0 1 129). That's the problem for me. **Kindly suggest:**

1. Why my regular expression is matching line no 3.
2. Correct regular expression that matches exactly either 4 no. of integers or 2 no. of double values in a line.

Comment: Or [`^(?<Values>(?:\d+\b\s*){4}|(?:\d+\.\d+\b\s*){2})$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3cValues%3e%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5cb%5cs*%29%7b4%7d%7c%28%3f%3a%5cd%2b%5c.%5cd%2b%5cb%5cs*%29%7b2%7d%29%5cr%3f%24&i=element+1+2%0d%0a8+24+2+1+1%0d%0a0+1+129%0d%0a2+2+0+0%0d%0a30.200001+1000.0000%0d%0a208+0+0+0+0+0+0+0&o=m)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
^(((\d+\s+){3}\d+)|(\d+\.\d*\s+\d+\.\d*))\s*$
```

Tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/jS8JwV/1).

---

**Explanations**

```
^(
  ((\d+\s+){3}\d+) # 4 numbers separated by at least one space
  |
  (\d+\.\d*\s+\d+\.\d*) # 2 floats separated by at least one space
)\s*$ # optional spaces at end of line (e.g., line 4)
```

The error in your initial attempt was the lack of mandatory space between numbers.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Is there any tool that can either generate a regex for me or at least guide me to create the regex?

Comment: I don't know any tool that can generate regexes, but the one I used to test (see link in my answer) helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Your regex says this:

```
(\d+\s*){4}
```

This means that it will match the following four times, as many times as possible:

- a series of numbers, followed by
- zero to unlimited spaces.

This is how it matches line 3:

0 1 12|9

Everything after the `|` is in group 4. What happens is that the engine sees 0 1 129 and thinks about how can it match 4 of `\d+\s*` out of this. Since whitespace is optional, it says ok, I will just split the number right before the 9. This way there are 4 of `\d+\s*`.

To solve this, you need to write a pattern that says match `\d+\s+` 3 times and `\d` 1 time. You also need to do this to the "2 decimal numbers" condition.

```
^(?<Values>(((\d+\s+){3}\d+)|(\d+\.\d+\s+)\d+\.\d+))\s*$
```

Comment: +1: minor nitpick... no need to parenthesize the first decimal number as there's no repetition count for it

Comment: @Sweeper,  Thanks a lot. It worked for me and I could also understand a bit about regex engine working in this case. Kindly suggest any link, I can refer to understand such basic knowledge of internal regex engines working.

Comment: @6502 I just left it there to make it clear that there are two of `\d+\.\d+\s+` Do you think it is clear enough?